# Modal in Angular 6 opened by jQuery Plugin only closes after two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jstree

I have a JSTree (jQuery Plugin) embedded in my Angular Application. 
The JSTree Plugin provides a context menu for tree elements, which I then use to call functions of my Angular component class (e.g. clicking "Preview Document" in the contextmenu calls the function previewDocument(x) of the component class).

Here is the code I use for that:

```
$(this.dataTree.nativeElement).jstree({
  contextmenu: {
    items: {
      preview: {
        action: (node: any) => {
          this.previewDocument(node.data.id);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ..........
});
```

The preview Document function calls a notification service which opens a MatDialog to display the requested document.

Now the problem: When I click the modal's close button, nothing happens. But when I click outside of the modal after that, it closes. Same thing with clicking outside of the modal first, I need to click somewhere inside the modal after that to finally close it.

There seems to be something wrong with refreshing the DOM here, because if I call that modal opening function normally (not through a jQuery Plugin), everything works just fine.

**How do I force a refresh of the DOM after the modal closes?**

PS: I use MatDialogRef.close(); to close the modal.

Comment: This is why you don't install jQuery in an Angular app, this will get you kicked off my team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the command is called from a jQuery plugin, it probably runs outside of the Angular [zone](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-ngzone), and therefore does not trigger change detection. You can force the code to run within the Angular zone by wrapping it in a `NgZone.run()` callback:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }
```

```
$(this.dataTree.nativeElement).jstree({
  contextmenu: {
    items: {
      preview: {
        action: (node: any) => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => {                // <-- Runs the code in Angular zone
            this.previewDocument(node.data.id);
          }); 
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ..........
});
```

[This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjgzrq?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts) simulates the jQuery problem by opening a dialog outside of the Angular zone. Another command opens the dialog in the zone, so that you can see the different behavior.

Comment: @Max - Did you have a chance to try this solution?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, worked like a charm! Thank you :)